# Where to set Visibility to False in Jetpack Compose? Relaunching Animation everytime Composable comes into view?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I would like to relaunch an animation everytime it comes into view, meaning if I scroll down a little with composable out of view, then scroll back up, the animation should relaunch. All the examples I've been seeing people have been setting the visibility to false with a button, however, I do NOT have a button. I would like it to be set whenever the composable is OUT of view. This is what I have so far:

```
    // ScreenFile
   @Composable
        FeaturePage{
          Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) {
        // I have tried changing this to LazyColumn and ran into crashes, data doesn't show correctly as LazyColumn either
          Feature1Component()
          Feature2Component()
          BarComponent()
         }
        }

@Composable
Feature2Component{
   Column(modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(20.dp)){
    //Other Components that don't have columns, but somehow this also conflicts, I have tried making this a LazyColumn as well, but data doesn't show correctly
}
}

@Composable
BarComponent{
   val listState = rememberLazyListState()

   var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

   LaunchedEffect(isLoading) {
        visible = true
    }

    val arrowLocation by animateOffsetAsState(
        targetValue = if (visible) arrowEndLocation else arrowStartLocation,
        animationSpec = tween(animationTime, animationDelayTime, easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing)
    )
   ConstraintLayout{
   Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(5.dp)){
    LeftColumn(modifier.constrainAs(left){//Content})
    RightColumn(modifier.constraintAs(Right){
       // Lazy Column
       Column{
       // Other content composables
       LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.requiredHeight(100.dp)){
          // Content I want to reanimate everytime its visible
       }
         }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

I feel like it wouldn't make sense to put it at the end of the Column because if I scroll up, the visibility won't be set to false right? Only at the bottom?

Comment: If you use a `LazyColumn` instead of a `Column` you can use the `LazyListState`APIs to know when the next visible item from the list comes into view and then if it is the correct item, start the animation. See the docs and examples here: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState#firstVisibleItemIndex()

Comment: @Ma3x Ohhhh interesting, thats a really good idea, let me try that right now.

Comment: @Ma3x Do you know if LazyGrid can do the same thing? I have multiple items within this column that need to be relaunched individually which each row comes into view

Comment: Yes, it seems it exposes the same API, see here https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/LazyGridState#firstVisibleItemIndex(). By knowing the `firstVisibleItemIndex`, then you can relaunch all items from `firstVisibleItemIndex` to `firstVisibleItemIndex + itemsInRow - 1` every time the `firstVisibleItemIndex` changes.

Comment: @Ma3x So I am running into an issue with this, this column is in another column in another column, I cannot change those to LazyColumns, so I can only put this one animated item in a LazyColumn, will the firstVisibleItem always be true if the LazyColumn doesn't take up the entire screen?

Comment: Can you update you question to show the hierarchy you are using? Is it 3 levels of Columns? The problem with Columns is that they will compose all their children regardless if these children are in view or not. So if you just have some tall Columns, then you probably won't benefit from a nested LazyColumn with just a single item.